# Pe Editing library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Anyone know of a good library for editing PE files? I tried PeLib but it is very basic and you pretty much have to do everything anyways.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, there is libbfd (the backend behind GCC and others): [Documentation](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/bfd/index.html) and [download](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/)

I took a quick look at the overview of PeLib, but it doesn't appear to be worse in accessibility. I don't know what you expect of such a library, but most object format libraries have no clue as to what you expect from them, and thus offer little specific access. In other words: such a library only saves you from parsing the object format.

If you want to do something specific, it helps if we know about it.

Comment: I want to add an import to a pe.

Comment: Just a hunch, but if you are compiling the input binary yourself, you could probably use the /INCLUDE argument to force linkage to a DLL function, and achieve the wanted effect without postprocessing altogether: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa278363%28VS.60%29.aspx

Comment: Well then, I'm out of easy solutions; You may still want to take a look at the initial answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Try LIEF https://lief.quarkslab.com

It even has python bindings, etc. 
It is multiplatform.